# Setting up stylesheet for mobile in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I use WP 4.9.2 and Leto theme from aThemes. The site that I built on it looks great on bigger screens, but is really screwed up in mobile. I checked the stylesheet - the problem is related to the @media queries. I just don't seem to be setting in the right way ( the css). So, I need to know how to style or what css to use to set the thing up. The theme I use is [Leto](https://athemes.com/theme/leto/), and I use WooCommerce plugin. So the responsiveness of the site is perfect on all pages but [this one, which in my opinion, utilizes WooCommerce](https://davoodkhan.net/opt2/my-account/). Anyone anywhere any help is welcome.
 Here is the `you can look up the whole stylesheet -->`[stylesheet](https://pastebin.com/XUntBwDi). You can download the theme in the first link, which was to [Leto](https://athemes.com/theme/leto/).

Comment: How you tested it on mobile? in real mobile device or browser

Comment: i confirm that all pages in the main menu of the link you provided use woocommerce. All pages also become broken when i reduce the browser window. That doesn't seem related to woocommerce but the way your header/menu is made. However, you should precise in your question what exactly you want to fix, this is too broad as it is. SO is made to answer specific problems.

Comment: @shojibur Tested it on both mobile and browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:280px) and (max-width:480px){}
@media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:619px){}
@media only screen and (min-width:620px) and (max-width:767px){}
```

like :

```
@media only screen and (min-width:280px) and (max-width:480px){
    body{ 
        do_stuff_here
    }
    .wrapper{
        do_stuff_here...
    }
}
```

OR Please read :
https://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_for_Mobile

Comment: Madhavi, Tonns of thanks for helping out! That worked perfectly.